# How to get the list of the external JavaScript used on my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to find out the list of JavaScript used on any given webpage also I need to know that if any of the included JS call to any other JS.

for example: we have www.test.com and we have xyz.js included in test.com. now the xyz.js call to some pqr.js.  so I need to know both xyz.js and pqr.js.

I am using PHP as a scripting language.

Comment: Explain it correctly please. What you want to do ?

Comment: If I think what you think you want. You can check all the stuff that's being loaded into a webpage by using the network tab of Chrome's developer tool(ctrl+shft+j)

Comment: check out in Scripts in resources in firebug for chrome and mozilla

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Else use chrome dev tools to inspect the network/sources calls this should list all the calls to scripts.  You might need to explain a little more on what your after, as if you have done xyz.js then you should now what being called within that script?

Answer (score 0):

if one javascript file requires another javascript file then you have to include the demanded javascript file to your page.

your javascript file can't import another javascript file in it.

so you can directly select the script tags on you page by jquery.

```
$("script[type='text/javascript']").each(function(index, scriptElement){
//do your code here counter++
```

})

where the index is the index of the each scriptElement and scriptElement is the current scriptElement.